# Extraction from Land Cover Raster Data

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to extract grassland values from a historical land use and land cover database created by USGS. I have some issues with the `Raster` package and `getValues` option. The tiff file is too large to add with this post, but it is available online.

The data is available under [Land-use and Land-cover Backcasting](https://landcover-modeling.cr.usgs.gov/projects.php).

This is my code:

```
 install.packages("raster")
 install.packages("rastervis")
 install.packages("RCurl")
 install.packages("R.utils")
 install.packages("rgdal")
 install.packages("sp")
 install.packages("maptools")
 install.packages("tibble")
 install.packages("ggplot2")
 install.packages("gridExtra")

 library(R.utils)
 library(rgdal)
 library(sp)
 library(maptools)
 library(raster)
 library(rasterVis)
 library(RCurl)
 library(R.utils)
 library(rgdal)
 library('rgdal')
 library('raster')
 library("tibble")
 library('ggplot2')
```

**Landcover file in tiff format:**

```
   Landcover1 <- raster ("CONUS_Backcasting_y1938.tif")
```

**USA counties file:**

```
   USA_county <- readOGR("UScounties",layer="UScounties")
```

**These two files are not in the same projection, so projection:**

```
 newprojection <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
 +towgs84=0,0,0"
 projected_raster_landcover1 <- projectRaster(Landcover1, crs = 
 newprojection)
```

**Now, I want to extract the land cover data only for the grassland (there are total 17 land classes, and grassland is coded as '11')**

```
 Landcover1_values <- extract(x = projected_raster_landcover1, 
                            y = USA_county)
```

**But when I use getValues to extract the grassland,**

```
 Landcover1_values_count<- lapply(Landcover1_values, FUN = function(x) {      
 length(which(getValues(x) == 11)) })
```

**it shows error:**

```
**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
 unable to find an inherited method for function ‘getValues’ for signature ‘"numeric", "missing", "missing"’**
```

I thought it is for `NA`, but I could not get how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/extract) returns a vector or a matrix while [`getValues`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/getValues) needs a raster as input. It's why you have this error.

Therefore, this should work in your case:

```
Landcover1_values_count <- sum(Landcover1_values == 11, na.rm = T)
```

Having said that, I am not sure about the use of `extract` in your workflow. I think what you are looking for is to mask your raster. So I suggest you use:

```
Landcover1_values <- mask(projected_raster_landcover1, USA_county)
Landcover1_values_count <- sum(Landcover1_values[,] == 11, na.rm = T)
```

**EDIT**

According to your comment, what you really want is to perform a zonal statistics (the number of pixels labeled as grasslands (11) in each county). Here are some steps on how to do it:

```
library(raster)
library(plyr)

# Function for efficient zonal stats using data.table, source: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-February/017475.html
myZonal <- function (x, z, stat, digits = 0, na.rm = TRUE, 
                     ...) { 

  library(data.table)
  fun <- match.fun(stat) 
  vals <- getValues(x) 
  zones <- round(getValues(z), digits = digits) 
  rDT <- data.table(vals, z=zones) 
  setkey(rDT, z) 
  rDT[, lapply(.SD, fun, na.rm = TRUE), by=z] 
} 

# Add an ID field to the shapefile
USA_county@data$ID <- c(1:length(USA_county@data[,1]))

# Crop raster to 'zone' shapefile extent
r <- crop(projected_raster_landcover1, extent(USA_county))

# Reclassify raster in binary raster with 1 for grasslands and 0 for all others values
r[r != 11] <- 0
r[r == 11] <- 1 

# Rasterize shapefile using ID field
zone <- rasterize(USA_county, r, field="ID", dataType = "INT1U") # Change dataType if nrow(USA_county) > 255 to INT2U or INT4U

# Zonal stats
Zstat <- data.frame(myZonal(r, zone, "sum"))
colnames(Zstat) <- c("ID", "Grassland")

# Merge data
USA_county@data <- plyr::join(USA_county@data, Zstat, by="ID")

# Show results
USA_county@data
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the help. It works perfect for the mask option, and I may misunderstand the "sum". Landcover1_values_count gives only one number, how can I make it by county? I want a county-level grassland data. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I made an edit. I assume that USA_county is a shapefile with a polygon for each county of interest.